# jquery date and time calculation firefox NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, calendar

I am trying to calculate days between certain date, I am using date and time.  On chrome works fine, but on Firefox gives me  "NaN", haven't test it on Ie, but I think it will be same result.

```
            <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="userForm" method="post">
            <table border="0">
            <tbody>            
              <tr class="rsform-block rsform-block-paemimodata">
                <td>Delivery Date (*)</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="datepicker rsform-input-box hasDatepicker" id="paemimodata" name="form[paemimodata]" size="20" value="2013-05-15"></td>

              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>Time (Hours) (*)</td>
                <td><select class="rsform-select-box" id="paemimolaikas" name=""><option value="01">01</option>
                    <option value="02">02</option>
                    <option value="03">03</option>
                    <option value="04">04</option>
                    <option value="05">05</option>
                    <option value="06">06</option>
                    <option value="07">07</option>
                    <option value="08">08</option>
                    <option value="09">09</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                  </select>
        </td>
              </tr>  
              <tr class="">
                <td>Time ( minutes )</td>
                <td><select class="rsform-select-box" id="paemimolaikasmin" name="">
                    <option value="05">05</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="35">35</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="45">45</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="55">55</option>
                    <option value="00">00</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
```

Return Date (*)
                    
                      
                  
                  
                    Time ( hours ) (*)
                    
                        01
                        02
                        03
                        04
                        05
                        06
                        07
                        08
                        09
                        10
                        11
                        12
                        13
                        14
                        15
                        16
                        17
                        18
                        19
                        20
                        21
                        22
                        23
                        24
                      
                    
                  
                  
                    Time ( minutes ) 
                    
                        05
                        10
                        15
                        20
                        25
                        30
                        35
                        40
                        45
                        50
                        55
                        00

```
        </form>
            </xmp>
```

Java Script

```
                <pre>


            jQuery(function ($) {

            function coundays () {


            var starter = $('#paemimodata').val();

            var starterhour = $('#paemimolaikas').val();
            var startermin = $('#paemimolaikasmin').val();


            var ender =  $('#grazinimodata').val();

            var enderhour = $('#grazinimolaikas').val();
            var endermin = $('#grazinimolaikasmin').val();

            var fullstarter = starter + ' ' +  starterhour + ':' + startermin + ':00';

            var fullender = ender + ' ' + enderhour + ':' + endermin + ':00';

                var start = new Date(fullstarter);
                var end = new Date(fullender);
            var diff = new Date(end - start);
            var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;


            alert(days);

            };


             coundays ();


               $('#userForm').on('change', function() {
                    coundays ();

              });






            });


                </pre>
```

Js fidlle

http://jsfiddle.net/dezignas/j2HGw/13/

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried using [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to pass a string to new Date which is ISO 8601 compliant, e.g. "2013-04-05T14:30". Then this should work for all modern browsers. In your case I think a T is missing between date and time.

Comment: Thanks, pointed at Right Direction added string "2013-04-05T14:30:00Z"

Answer (score 0):

Date should be RFC2822 compliant as stated on Mozilla documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Change the date assign to this:

```
var fullstarter = starter + 'T' +  starterhour + ':' + startermin + ':00';
var fullender = ender + 'T' + enderhour + ':' + endermin + ':00';
```